# Is the example in wikipedia about 3NF conform it?

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization, third-normal-form

This is screenshot from the article about [normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org).
[image]

There is stated that in order to conform `3NF` the `Genre Name` column must be put to it's own dictionary table.

My question is, is the `Author Nationality` breaking `3NF` there also?

Comment: Wikipedia is mostly rubbish re the relational model. And that article is trash. Read a published academic information modeling & database design textbook. stanford.edu has a free online course. Explain "breaking 3NF" using proper technical terms. Give your justification by appealing to definitions. Otherwise you are just asking us to write yet another presentation & a bespoke tutorial. PS Use text, not images/links, for text, including tables (format as code) & ERDs (give DDL). Use images for what cannot be given as text or to augment text.

Comment: Also see my comment on the accepted answer re its problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, `Author Nationality` is also breaking 3NF.

Explanation is as follows. `Book` can identify `author`, but not the other way round. Therefore `author` is functionally dependent on book. Same thing for `author` and `author nationality`. `Author nationality` is functionally dependent on `author`. There you have your transitive dependency: `author nationality` -> `author` -> `book`.

Another thing that could be optimized in the book table would be the column `thickness`. It's functionally dependent on `pages`. Having that in an extra table would be overkill though, as this information can be easily derived from `pages`. I personally wouldn't store that information in the database. If you want to have this information in the database, you could create a view like

```
CREATE VIEW v_book AS 
SELECT b.*, 
case when pages between 0 and 100 then 'slim' else 'thick' end as thickness 
FROM book b;
```

The book table should look like

```
book | author_id | pages | genre_id | publisher_id
```

with another table author

```
author_id | author_name | author_nationality
```

Comment: This is not all correct. You have the FDs/arrows in the wrong direction in nationality -> author -> book. Also it's not clear what you think is the transitive FD there. Also your reasoning is wrong; FDs violating 3NF are transitive FDs of non-prime (CK) attributes on CKs. And X->Y transitively when for some A X->A->Y and not A->Z. Also "optimized" is not only unclear but bad wording when thickness is a function of pages since having both violates 3NF per FD pages->thickness.

Comment: @philipxy I must admit, I'm not very experienced in this matter and I got my knowledge from books like "usage driven database design" which orients more on the practical side than theory. Your comments are a bit hard to understand. Why don't you write an answer that explains this in more detail?

Comment: Hi. What is the first thing you don't understand in my comment? Re me answering see my comment on the question: it should be closed as too broad, not answered.